# How to convert the type *http Cookies into string using gin package

Tags: go, cookies

By ajax I'm setting the cookies and in go middleware I'm just taking the cookies but its a type of *http Cookies and I just want to generate the string then what should I have to use to do this.

**Code**:-

```
headerToken,_ := c.Request.Cookie("X-Test-Header")
fmt.Println(headerToken)
```

> ```
> output is `X-Test-Header=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InB1bmVldEBiay5jb20iLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IjEyMzQ0In0.x0INnR3anZXjPEtwZSmG3pAX5RZjJSmZ`
> ```

```
//but now I'm splits this and converting into the string 
headerTok := strings.Join(headerToken," ")
```

Issue I want to generate the above output into a string after the `=`.can anyone tell me how I will do this.

I will tried this type of code

```
s := strings.Split(headerToken, "=")
ip, port := s[0], s[1]
fmt.Println(ip, port)
```

the above code will give me the error of :-

## error

> ```
> cannot use headerToken (type *http.Cookie) as type string in argument to strings.Split
> ```

Can anyone help me. Thank you. if this is basic question then sorry I really don't know this.

Comment: Use `headerToken.Value`? (https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Cookie)

Comment: to clarify, https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Cookie returns an `*http.Cookie` object, *not* a string, that object contains everything you need to know about the cookie, name, *value*, etc. Passing objects that implement the [`String`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Cookie.String) method to the `fmt.Println` function will cause that `String` method to be called instead of "dumping" the object as you might expect. In the future you can use `fmt.Printf("%#v", cookie)` to tell `fmt` not to call `String`. https://play.golang.org/p/WZXEmdhySUY

Comment: ...and as you can already probably tell you don't have to split anything. `Cookie.Value` contains what you need, that part after `=`, the "value" of the cookie.

Comment: @mkopriva thankyou it works

Comment: @Flimzy it is, I know and I assume it stems from their confusion of what the `Cookie` method returns. I kept it in my comment only because that's what they used to name the variable. They are also mixing up the convention for header names with cookie names...

Answer (score 4):

You haven't specified which string you want, but assuming you want the cookie *value*, just access the [`Value` field of the `Cookie` object](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Cookie):

```
cookie, err := req.Cookie("cookie-name")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
value := cookie.Value
```